# Using a Select List Alongside a File Upload on Razor Pages

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, selectlist

**Background:**
The program uses .Net Core 3.1 along with EF Core leveraging a local instance of MSSQL using a code-first approach.
Relevant entities for the problem include the Agent

```
public class Agent
    {
        public int AgentID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SysInfo> SysInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

which has a one to many relationship with SysInfo

```
public class SysInfo
    {
        public int SysInfoID { get; set; }
        public int AgentID { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
        public Agent Agent { get; set; }
    }
```

DB is built using EF Core migrations, CRUD pages are scaffolded for the Agent entity. SysInfo is intended to store system information files.
I started with the example I found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#file-upload-scenarios and modified the UploadDbModel to include a select list.

```
 public class BufferedSingleFileUploadDbModel:PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public BufferedSingleFileUploadDb FileUpload { get; set; }
        public SelectList AgentNameSL { get; set; }
        public void PopulateAgentsDropDownList(WindowsAuthTest3Context _context, object selectedAgent = null)
        {
            var agentsQuery = from a in _context.Agent
                              orderby a.Name
                              select a;
            AgentNameSL = new SelectList(agentsQuery.AsNoTracking(), "AgentID", "Name", selectedAgent);
        }
    }
    public class BufferedSingleFileUploadDb
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="File")]
        public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
    }
```

The upload page is scaffolded out from a standard EF core Create template and is modified to inherit the class above, populate the select list, handle the upload and create the record.

**Problem:**
I'm doing something wrong when I'm attempting to mesh the select list with the multipart enctype. The select list refuses to populate when I load the page.

CS file:

```
public class UploadModel : BufferedSingleFileUploadDbModel
    {
        private readonly WindowsAuthTest3.Data.WindowsAuthTest3Context _context;

        public UploadModel(WindowsAuthTest3.Data.WindowsAuthTest3Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            PopulateAgentsDropDownList(_context);
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public SysInfo SysInfo { get; set; }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync()
        {
            
            using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await FileUpload.FormFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                SysInfo.Content = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            _context.SysInfo.Add(SysInfo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
```

CSHTML file:

```
@page
@model WindowsAuthTest3.Pages.Infos.UploadModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Upload";
}

<h1>Upload</h1>

<h4>SysInfo</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SysInfo.AgentID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="SysInfo.AgentID" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.AgentNameSL"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="FileUpload.FormFile"></label>
                    <input asp-for="FileUpload.FormFile" type="file">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Can select lists be included in multipart enctypes and if so am I just writing this wrong?
2. If not, how would I structure multiple post methods to accomplish setting the foreign key while uploading the file? I've considered making the agent ID nullable and then assigning this through an edit page but that feels like a terrible workaround prone to user error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After separating the post methods I noticed the select list would populate, then disappear after uploading the file. This appears to be due to the asp-page-handler. I combined the code into the regular post method as shown below and now everything is working.

CSHTML

````
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SysInfo.AgentID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="SysInfo.AgentID" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.AgentNameSL"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FileUpload.FormFile"></label>
                <input asp-for="FileUpload.FormFile" type="file">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>```
````

CS

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await FileUpload.FormFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                SysInfo.Content = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            _context.SysInfo.Add(SysInfo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

Comment: Good job on figuring it out. I ran into a very similar problem just a couple weeks ago. The IFormFile kept coming back null. I was able to get it by doing what I did in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way you could use this html in your razor page:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <dl>
                <dt>
                    <label>Choose File</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <input name="file" type="file">
                </dd>
            </dl>
    <input asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Then in your OnPostUpload method in page model just pass in your IFormFile file as a parameter:

```
public IActionResult OnPostUpload(IFormFile file)
```